# dynamodb.Table.query gives incomplete response, but only for one value of the range key

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, boto3, dynamodb-queries

I have a dynamodb table with a number of global secondary indices on it.  When I query one particular index I get a response that is missing slightly over 400 items, but only for one specific value of the range key.

How do I troubleshoot this?

```
>>> resp = table.query(IndexName='group_index', KeyConditionExpression=Key('group').eq('CLOUD') & Key('gsi_artificial_pk').eq(1))
>>> [x for x in resp['Items'] if x['id'] == 18692]
[]
>>> item = table.get_item(Key={'id': '18962'})['Item']
>>> item['group']
'CLOUD'
>>> item['gsi_artificial_pk']
Decimal('1')
```

To add to my confusion, if I run the same query on the same index with the same key conditions from the console, id 18962 is present in the response.

For every other value of 'group' that we use, I get a complete set of responses from the same query.

Even my rubber duck hasn't been able to help here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably your query call is returning the first page of results and you’re not noticing the LastEvaluatedKey in the response and the need to pull the subsequent pages.

The console and CLI will pull additional pages for you implicitly. That’s why you see the data there.

Comment: Correct, thanks.  Now off to figure out why that query *isn't* failing for the even larger groups...

Comment: Glad you've got it working! I'd encourage you to not see it as failing, just paging. A client that wants to pull a full data set should always watch for LastEvaluatedKey to know if there's another page to pull.